# commandButton actionListener not called when page reloaded

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, jboss

I am creating a JSF application with primefaces(3.2). Basically I have this tabview. There is a tab view which for each tab contains a command button. The first time I am able to invoke the actionListener and redirecting to home screen. Now when I come back to this page none of the actionListeners is invoking the methods.

I have attached the simplified xhtml code.

```
<h:form id="syncpasswdform">
    <p:tabView id="tabviewid" onTabChange="tabChangeEvent();">
        <p:tab title="#{msg.sync_pwd_nw_per}" >
            <p:commandButton  id="syncbutton" 
                              actionListener="#{SyncPasswordBean.syncPassword}"  
                              value="#{msg.sync_pwd_nw_res_pwds}">
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="#{msg.sync_pwd_nw_nonpers}">
            <p:commandButton  id="non_pers_syncbutton" 
                              actionListener="#{NonPersonalSyncPasswordBean.syncPassword}"  
                              value="#{msg.sync_pwd_nw_nonpers_res_pwds}">
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error in your backing bean. Try to set option `ajax="false"` in your p:commandButton to actually see the error. 
Hope it helps.